# downsample dask dataframe - possibly stratified

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask

I have a large dask dataframe with a dependent variable Y to be used for binary probabilistic classification. I would like to down sample this (ideally stratified supposedly based on priors of Y?). can this easily be achieved? Any code snippets would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I tackled a simple downsample (all of the target event records where grossresponse==1, and an equal number of non-event records) with a dask dataframe this way. this was python 3.7.6, pandas 1.0.3, dask 2.15.0 on an AWS EMR cluster running Hadoop 2.8.5-amzn-5.

As @MRocklin notes, you could do this the same way in pandas. There's nothing unique about this being done in dask compared to pandas, but it does run effectively on our dask cluster.

```py
# build a stratified sample of all the responders and an equal size sample of non-responders
print("Pulling an EDA sample")
ResponderCount = pd_nrm_both_post_encode.query("GrossResponse == 1").shape[0].compute()
TotalCount = pd_nrm_both_post_encode.shape[0].compute()
nr_fraction = ResponderCount / TotalCount
print("Responders count: " + str(ResponderCount))
print("pulling responders")
nrm_responders = pd_nrm_both_post_encode.query("GrossResponse == 1")
print("pulling non-responders")
nrm_nonResponders = pd_nrm_both_post_encode.query("GrossResponse == 0").sample(frac=nr_fraction, random_state=1)
print("appending responders and non-responders")
dd_nrm_eda_train_sample = nrm_responders.append(nrm_nonResponders)
```

Comment: PS you can control the downsampling rate by the .sample() method's frac= parameter. in this case, frac was set by the responder rate from the population. you could modify this however you saw fit. if you wanted to do this in a stratified downsampling, I havent tackled this yet but perhaps a list comprehension would be one decent approach. Not sure what would scale the best.